# SQL select max date that is smaller than specific date

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, max

im trying to make a query in Access that selects the MAX date from a table, that is smaller than the date of specific other record in the table, and i have to check if that record exists.

I know the description is a bit confusing, so i will try to explain it in pseudocode:

```
If(Record exists where editing_type = "Notranja kontrola")
   SELECT MAX(created_at) that is smaller than ( MIN(created_at) Where 
   editing_type = "Notranja kontrola") 
   WHERE editing_type = "Zajem"
```

If the record with editing_type = "Notranja kontrola" doesnt exists, <strike>i don't want to select a date.</strike> i want to return NULL.
If it does, i want to select max date where editing_type = "Zajem", that is smaller than MIN(date) WHERE editing_type = "Notranja kontrola")

The query i came up with:

```
SELECT 
spr.ob_id AS Obcina, 
spr.ko, 
'DA' AS Dodeljeno,
(   
SELECT MAX(created_at)
FROM ( 
    SELECT created_at
    FROM spremljanje_uporabnik_zajem
    WHERE created_at < (
        SELECT MIN(created_at)
        FROM spremljanje_uporabnik_zajem
        WHERE editing_type = "Notranja kontrola" AND ko = spr.ko AND VAL(ko) BETWEEN  0 AND 9999
        )
    )   
WHERE editing_type = "zajem" AND ko = spr.ko AND VAL(ko) BETWEEN  0 AND 9999
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM spremljanje_uporabnik_zajem
        WHERE editing_type = "Notranja kontrola" AND ko = spr.ko AND VAL(ko) BETWEEN  0 AND 9999
    )
) AS [krneki],

(SELECT
.....


)

FROM spremljanje_uporabnik_zajem AS spr

WHERE VAL(ko) BETWEEN  0 AND 9999

GROUP BY spr.ob_id, spr.ko

ORDER BY Val(spr.ko);
```

the `WHERE VAL(ko) BETWEEN  0 AND 9999` part is only to check if the entry is valid.

When i try to run the query, i get a prompt asking me to input spr.ko, instead of taking it as a value form the outer query.
How do i fix this?

The outer query is there because i need to select some other things too.

EDIT + EDIT2: 
Im only selecting from table "spremlanje_uporabniki_zajem"

Sample data(spremlanje_uporabniki_zajem):

```
    ob_id   ko     editing_type        created_at
    40      100       zajem             1.01.2018
    40      100       zajem             2.01.2018
    40      100  notranja kontrola      3.01.2018
    40      100       zajem             4.01.2018
    90      550       zajem             2.01.2018
    40      100       zajem             6.01.2018
    40      20        zajem             7.01.2018
    40      20        zajem             8.01.2018
    40      20   notranja kontrola      9.01.2018
    40      20        zajem            10.01.2018
    40      100       zajem            11.01.2018
    40      20        zajem            12.01.2018
    40      20  notranja kontrola      13.01.2018
    40     100  notranja kontrola      13.01.2018


Expected REXPECTED RESULT:      


    ob_id    ko   Dodeljeno     krneki
      40    100      DA       2.01.2018
      90    550      DA          NULL
      40    20       DA       8.01.2018
```

Thank you

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Sorry, i know my question is confusing but i dont know how to explain it better, english is not my primary language. I will add datat as text.

Comment: More data examples will also help understand the problem. And explain the logic using your sample data. Include multiple `kontrola`  rows so we can see the MIN, MAX restriction

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First you need calculate the `MIN(date)` for each group
- Then you perform a LEFT JOIN to get the rows with date previous to that found `MIN(date)`
- Now you group all those row together
- Using conditional `MAX(CASE)` you remove the date with null values.

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2cf0b/14)

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT  "ob_id", "ko", MIN("created_at") min_kontrola
      FROM Table1 
      WHERE "editing_type" = 'notranja kontrola'
      GROUP BY "ob_id", "ko"
)  
SELECT t."ob_id", 
       t."ko", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.min_kontrola IS NOT NULL 
                THEN t."created_at"
           END) as krneki
FROM Table1 t 
LEFT JOIN cte c
  ON t."ob_id" = c."ob_id"
 AND t."ko" = c."ko"
 AND t."created_at" < c.min_kontrola
GROUP BY t."ob_id", t."ko" 
ORDER BY  t."ob_id", t."ko";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ob_id |  ko |        max |
|-------|-----|------------|
|    40 |  20 | 2018-01-08 |
|    40 | 100 | 2018-01-02 |
|    90 | 550 |     (null) |
```

In the SQL DEMO you have two queries. The second one I remove the `GROUP BY` so you can see the result before the last steps.

Comment: MS Access does not seem to support CTE's

Comment: Sorry I miss the access tag. But that doesnt mean you cant rewrite it as a subquery, can you?

Comment: Thanks, after figuring out how CTE's work and modyfing query to work in access it woks as expected.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can take this query and finish the rest yourself.

```
select
  t3.ob_id,
  t3.ko,
  t4.max_created_at
from(
select distinct
  ob_id,
  ko
from dummyTable
) t3
left join (
SELECT
  t1.ob_id,
  t1.ko,
  max(t1.created_at) max_created_at
from dummyTable t1
where exists (
  select
    1
  from dummyTable t2
  where t2.ob_id = t1.ob_id and
  t2.ko = t1.ko and
  t2.editing_type = 'nontranja kontrola' and
  t1.created_at < t2.created_at
)) t4
on t4.ob_id = t3.ob_id and
t4.ko = t3.ko
```

You can try it out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f0a5/9/0).

Comment: Your query remove the null row

Comment: i edited my answer so the rows with null values arent removed

Comment: You can use this tool to format your query http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: OP add additional data, you can use my fiddle instead. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2cf0b/14

Comment: appreciated. My solution with additonal data and with postgresql syntax insted of mysql syntax can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2cf0b/20/0

Comment: The query from the last link does not return expected result, it seems to return the date of the last record before the most recent  "notranja kontrola", i want to get the date of the last record before oldest "notranja kontrola".

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the "NULL requirement", I had to revise my answer. Your query wasn't too bad, but I found some things to improve/correct:

- The "zajem WHERE clause" mustn't be a WHERE clause but additional criteria for the WHERE clause on the next inner level.
- The "EXISTS criterion" can be removed, because when no record exists, also the `MIN` doesn't exist, and so the comparison with any "zajem record" will fail, which will result in "no maximum" (NULL) as desired.
- There is no need for a "zajem subquery", the criteria can be applied directly in the "MAX query".

What has come out of that is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    spr.ob_id AS Obcina
  , spr.ko
  , 'DA' AS Dodeljeno
  , (   
        SELECT MAX(created_at)
        FROM spremljanje_uporabnik_zajem
        WHERE editing_type = "zajem" AND ko = spr.ko AND VAL(ko) BETWEEN  0 AND 9999
          AND created_at < (
            SELECT MIN(created_at)
            FROM spremljanje_uporabnik_zajem
            WHERE editing_type = "Notranja kontrola" AND ko = spr.ko AND VAL(ko) BETWEEN  0 AND 9999
            )
    ) AS [krneki]
FROM spremljanje_uporabnik_zajem AS spr
WHERE VAL(ko) BETWEEN  0 AND 9999
GROUP BY spr.ob_id, spr.ko
ORDER BY VAL(spr.ko);
```

And Access can run it without any hickup:

[image: query result]

Comment: This query doesn't return the NULL rows.

Comment: @KrEn You said *If the record with editing_type = "Notranja kontrola" doesnt exists, i dont want to select a date*. Doesn't that mean that nothing should appear?

Comment: my bad, in that case i want to return NULL in "krneki" field, but still select other things (see the expected result table)

Comment: @KrEn Now, I think I understood what you mean, I revised my answer (completely).

Answer (score 0):

Solution, in case anyone is interested (modified from @Juan Carlos Oropeza post - replacing CTE with subquery and using MS Access syntax)

```
SELECT 
    t.ob_id, 
    t.ko, 
    MAX(iif(c.min_kontrola IS NOT NULL,t.created_at)) as krneki,

FROM spremljanje_uporabnik_zajem t

LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT  ob_id, ko, MIN(created_at) AS min_kontrola
    FROM spremljanje_uporabnik_zajem 
    WHERE editing_type = 'notranja kontrola'
    GROUP BY ob_id, ko
    )AS c

ON (t.ob_id = c.ob_id
AND t.ko = c.ko
AND (t.created_at < c.min_kontrola)
AND VAL(t.ko) BETWEEN 0 AND 9999
AND t.editing_type = "zajem"
)
GROUP BY t.ob_id, t.ko 
ORDER BY  t.ob_id, t.ko;
```